# Best optimizer in Matlab for this problem?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, matlab

I need to do yield curve extraction for fixed income. I have 10 fixed income instruments for which I have values.

The method is called Nelson-Siegel Method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-income_attribution

The equation is  $y\left( m \right) = \beta _0  + \beta _1\frac{{\left[ {1 - \exp \left( { - m/\tau} \right)} \right]}}{m/\tau} + \beta _2  {\left(\frac{{\left[ {1 - \exp \left( { - m/\tau} \right)} \right]}}{m/\tau} - \exp \left( { - m/\tau}\right)\right)} $

I need to optimize the value of tau and the betas. This is basically OLS problem. Not sure which optimizer in Matlab and how to solve this problem. Need some guidance on solving this problem.

Comment: "Best" means what? Try `nlinfit` or `lsqnonlin`.

Comment: best means the one that produces the minimum error between actual prices and the one that is calculated using the method above..

Comment: If you know the actual prices, then you can always use the squared error with fminsearch. I don't know if it's optimal, but it's so easy to use that it's usually the first thing I try.

Comment: how do u fminsearch with many variables? do u know?

Comment: @lakesh I'm not sure what you mean. Did you look at the examples provided with matlab? If not, use `doc fminsearch` and read through it.

Comment: Just try a few different methods and see what gives you the best result (e.g. levenberg-marquardt, congugate gradients etc)

Comment: Could you tell what is given / known and what is searched for?